# Unable to dequeue a cell with identifier cellID. Same code works fine on older Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Since I shifted my app to my new computer I'm getting the error:

> Unable to dequeue a cell with identifier cellID

though the code is exactly the same as it was on my old computer and on my old computer it works fine.

Here is the code from the page giving the error:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class ServiceTypeSelector: UITableViewController,UINavigationBarDelegate {
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    let sections = ["All Users & Services"]
    let services = [["All Users & Services"]]

    //active for business accounts only

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray

        guard let serviceBeingSearched = self.defaults.string(forKey: "Service being searched") else { return }

        navigationItem.title = serviceBeingSearched

        self.navigationController!.navigationBar.topItem!.title = ""

        tableView.register(ServiceCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cellId")
        tableView.register(Header.self, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: "headerId")

        tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = 50
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        let serviceBeingSearched = self.defaults.string(forKey: "Service being searched")

        if serviceBeingSearched == nil {
            defaults.set("All Users & Services", forKey: "Service being searched")

            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return sections.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return services[section].count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let serviceTypeCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as! ServiceCell

        var service = serviceTypeCell.refinementsLabel.text
        service = services[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]

        defaults.set(service, forKey: "Service being searched")

        guard let serviceBeingSearched = self.defaults.string(forKey: "Service being searched") else { return }

        navigationItem.title = serviceBeingSearched

        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let serviceTypeCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as! ServiceCell
        serviceTypeCell.refinementsLabel.text = services[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]

        serviceTypeCell.sectionsSelector = self

        return serviceTypeCell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        return tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: "headerId")
    }
}

class ServiceCell: UITableViewCell {
    var serviceTypeSelector: ServiceTypeSelector?

    //all other code removed for simplicity for the question
}
```

Comment: Check in Interface Builder (your storyboard) that the cell identifier is set to "cellId"

Comment: Calling `dequeueReusableCell` in `didSelectRowAt` does definitely **not** work in older Swift versions. Unrelated but what is the purpose of saving a value to user defaults and read it back immediately? You **know** the value.

Comment: vadian dequeueReusableCell in didSelectRowAt does definitely not work in older Swift versions , it is working fine in xcode 8.3.

Comment: davecom my app is built programmatically not using storyboards?

Comment: It cannot work, never, not even in xcode 8.3. You get an random reused cell which is **not** the corresponding cell at the given index path. This is the wrong way anyway: Never get data from the **view** (the cell), get it from the **model** (the data source array)

Comment: its was and works because the var service was changed to = services[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let serviceTypeCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as! ServiceCell
```

You *must* not dequeue a cell in `didSelectRowAt`.

Comment: it working fine on my old computer? though how else would i get the refinementsLabel.text from the cell i click on?

Answer (score 0):

It's not right to call dequeReusableCell in didSelectRowat method.
Use cellForRowAtIndexPath instead.